# How publishing my API Rest with Heroku?

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, heroku, publish

I just created a Rest API with NodeJs + express with MySQL, it works in localhost, but now I would like to use it online.

I have tested Heroku and have created a Heroku app, afterward I do `git push heroku master`, but I have a permission problem :

```
Counting objects: 3885, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3683/3683), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3885/3885), 4.95 MiB | 76.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3885 (delta 736), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_3509cb4460806c73d75c851251539522/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-05T20_37_55_505Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:        https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to whispering-scrubland-23624.
remote:
```

I tried as administrator but it does not change anything. I also tried to install before node-pre-gyp but it does not change anything, I still have the same problem.

Did you have any idea to solve this problem, please?

Comment: Are you talking about deploying this to somewhere so it's live?

Comment: Probably the easiest option would be to deploy the app to Heroku. You can find some tutorials on their site, such as this one for deploying a nodejs app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Comment: yes, to use it with my apps. Alright i'll take that

Comment: I suggest you to use Heroku, the easiest one.
Here you can find the [instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) for deploying to Heroku.
But, be careful with MySQL, because it can be difficult to deploy your stack here. A lot of resources will show you how to deploy node.js with postgres.
But take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413145/6805529). Hope this will help

Comment: In addition, if you want to learn something new and interesting, please take a look at this [article](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/migrating-a-nodejs-rest-api-off-heroku-and-on-to-elastic-beanstalk). 
And here is the [documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html) to use Node.js with
AWS Elastic Beanstalk.